# How to save spark rdd to an csv file

Tags: node.js, csv

I have an requirement to retrieve the cassandra table data and save it to file system (linux file system).

The file should not split into multiple node, it should be create in one single node.

We have four node (datastax) cassandra cluster running with spark mode.
dse version: 5.0.1
Spark Version: 1.6.1

Hereis my sample code:

```
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext1 = new CassandraSQLContext(sc);
sqlContext1.setKeyspace("KeyspaceName");
val results = sqlContext1.sql("SELECT * FROM KeyspaceName.TableName");
 results.collect().foreach(println);
```

Now the results RDD. need to save to local file system (linux) in one single node.

I followed some of the blogs but didn't work. Can some one guide to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The output location needs to be accessible by all nodes in your spark cluster. You can map a location as a network folder and specify that as your output location.

**Spark 2+** 
`results.write.csv(path_to_network_folder)`

**Spark 1.6 with Scala 2.11** 
add dependency `spark-csv` from https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv like so: 
`libraryDependencies += "com.databricks" % "spark-csv_2.11" % "1.5.0"`

The code will look something like this:
`results.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save(path_to_network_folder)`

Comment: I have tried using csv function, but it's throwing the below error..

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter

scala> results.write.csv("file://home/cassandra/test.csv")
<console>:85: error: value csv is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter
              results.write.csv("file://home/cassandra/test.csv")

Comment: oh sorry, didn't notice you were using Spark 1.6.1. The csv function was introduced in Spark 2.0. but if you can't upgrade, you might want to take a look at this: https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

Comment: if you're using sbt, import the library: `libraryDependencies += "com.databricks" % "spark-csv_2.11" % "1.5.0"`.  Then your code will look something like this: `results.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save(path_to_network_folder)`